# How to extract "buyer" and "seller" from a contract

Tags: nlp

I'm learning about natural language processing and I'm wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.
Say I have a bunch of contracts, and they have something like:

```
Joe's Farm, hereafter known as the seller, 
and Bob's supermarket, hereafter known as the buyer, blah blah..
```

I'd like to be able to identify which party is the buyer and seller in this sentence. From what I have read, it should be theoretically possible to:

```
1. Give the AI a lot of sample sentences and tell it "this is the buyer/seller".
2. After training, it should be able to analyze a new sentence.
```

I have tried some entity extraction (tokenizing the sentence and identifying the party names) but I don't know how to tell it "this party is the buyer".
One workaround is to identify segments of the sentence and search if that has the word "buyer" in it... which probably works in most cases, but I want to try to do this in an "AI" way.

Can anyone point me to the right direction on what to research?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a [coreference resolution](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/coref.shtml) problem to me.

[image: Example]

[Stanford CoreNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/coref.html) may be a good starting point. It comes with a deterministic, a statistical, and a neural system, as well as pre-trained models.

Comment: Thanks, I tried running the sample code, and was able to get pronouns out of the box. How do I "give" it training data so that it can identify these "seller" and "buyer" clauses? I used this: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/coref.html but I don't know how to customize it for my needs...

Comment: Did you have a look at the “Training New Models” section? https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/coref.html#training-new-models

Answer (score 1):

How you solve that problem will depend on several factors, most importantly:

- Do all contracts have the **same format**?
- After specifying the **seller** and the **buyer** as you showed in your examples, do their real names appear again the text? Or just referred to as **seller** and **buyer**?

With that in mind, let's assume that the contracts have various formats and that the proper/real names of the seller and the buyer appear only once in the text somewhere in the introduction of the contract. This second assumption simplifies the problem (and is more likely to be the case in real-world contracts).

I would tackle the problem in three steps:

1. Teach the program how to identify the introduction of the contract (i.e. the paragraph in which the contract says who is who; kinda like your example sentences.)
2. Split the introduction into two parts: the part/sentence(s) where the seller is defined and the part/sentence(s) where the buyer is defined.
3. Finally, look into the **seller** part to find who the seller is and the **buyer** part to find who the buyer is.

To solve the **1st step**, a small training dataset would be necessary. If not available, you could manually identify introductions of several contracts and use them as your training dataset. From here, **Naive Bayes** would probably be the simplest way to identify if a section of the contract is an introduction or not (*you can randomly divide the contract into multiple chunks*). Naive Bayes relies only on the frequency of tokens (not the ordering). You can read more [here](http://www3.nd.edu/~dchiang/teaching/nlp/2016/notes/chapter2v2.pdf).

To solve the **2nd step**, I would pretty much repeat what's done in the first step: use a dataset to "classify" sections of the introduction as the **seller part** and the **buyer part**. Though, this step will probably require more accuracy than the first one. So, I suggest doing a **n-gram language model**. That looks at the frequency of tokens, but also the ordering and succession. You can read more [here](http://www3.nd.edu/~dchiang/teaching/nlp/2016/notes/chapter5v5.pdf). For a n-gram, you want something in between: not too short (1-gram = Naive Bayes) and not too long (> ~ 6-gram) to avoid much overlaps between the **seller** and **buyer** sentences.

For the **3rd and last step**, I cannot think of a straightforward way, but I would remove the stop words (i.e. frequent English words) first. Then, I would try to find rare words in close proximity to the target terms (**buyer** and **seller**). Since we are assuming that the real names only appear once in the contract, that could be a rule that helps you identify them.

There are probably many other things you can try depending on the size/availability of training datasets, but this should give you a start.

Comment: Thanks. As a complete beginner to NLP, there are still a lot of concepts (and maths) that I don't really understand so it will take me some to actually implement your answer. If you know of any java resources, that would be really helpful.

Comment: @sikidhart, I am not familiar with java (I mostly use python), but I am sure a few Google searches (e.g. `nlp java library`) should point you in the right direction.